# Area Outline in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

In all other browsers, including IE10, this CSS removes the outline when clicking on a mapped area on an image anchor:

```
area {
     outline: none;
}
```

But lo and behold, not in IE11, at least not the latest version I can get for Win7. A quick demo page: *(demo removed)*. Click on a thumbnail; on the full-sized images, the right 60% is a link to the next image, the left 40% to the previous image.

I've tried all manner of CSS variations, including:

```
outline: none !important;
```

Applying it to every CSS class and ID I can think of seems to make no difference, including `*`, `img`, `map`, `area`, `.gr-slideimage`, `#gr-thisMap`, and so on. The only thing I've found so far that works is the old:

```
hidefocus='true'
```

on the img tag itself, but that doesn't validate, of course.

Can anyone crack this with CSS?

Comment: Have you tried by any chance `outline: 0;`? I don't have IE11 to check. Besides, why are you using such a solution for navigating through your images? I find it quite unsemantic...

Comment: Yes, I've tried outline: 0, as well as outline: transparent solid 1px, outline: white solid 0px, and so on.

Comment: why not go a "traditional" way of doing things and make a link to the next page a semantic `a` tag (if you reload the page) or make it a `button` if you don't.. then the only thing you'll do is position the navigation

Comment: @skip405: Interesting, but not the topic of this thread. I'm just looking for an answer to the question I posted, not for a discussion of other aspects of the page design. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

IE11/Win7 seems to ignore border settings set to 'none' in some circumstances. Had this issue with CSS styled buttons this week. I had to make the border 'solid' and change the color to match. Sure there's a better way - surely MisterNeutron and I aren't the only ones to notice this bug?

Comment: Actually, I'm affected, too. No solution so far unfortunately.

Comment: I fixed the stray border. In my case we had `border-style:none` to disable borders on input elements. However, IE11, for whatever sick reason, also needs a `border-width:0` or it will just pseudo-randomly choose a border style on elements it thinks should have a border.

Comment: Alas, on an "area" element, IE11 ignores even this combination (using outline-style and outline-width, rather than border).

Answer (score -1):

It appears IE11 needs outline-style: none; in order to work properly.  You can also refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304065(v=vs.85).aspx for any other possible IE related issue.  Hope this helps.